# not able to run java application from command line

Tags: java

I am trying to run  java desktop application using command line.In this application I am  using the  serial port to communicate ans send and receive request and response.So i am using the RXTXserail.dll file and RXTXcomm.jar file.I am creating the application using net beans 7.1 version under the windows 7 OS.
It was  running from net beans  plate form but when i try to run the application jar file that time i am getting this below error

```
"C:\configurationtool\ModbusZigBee\dist>java -jar ModbusZigBee.jar
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\rxtxSerial.dll: C
an't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform thrown while loading gnu.io.RX
TXCommDriver
        Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Progra
m Files\Java\jre6\bin\rxtxSerial.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit
platformSubstance Raven Graphite failed to initialize

        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
        at modbuszigbee.SerialInterface.<init>(SerialInterface.java:58)
        at modbuszigbee.ModbusZigBeeView.<init>(ModbusZigBeeView.java:111)
        at modbuszigbee.ModbusZigBeeApp.startup(ModbusZigBeeApp.java:22)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

I am using 32 bit java 6  in my system. and rxtxserial.dll also 32 bit.i tried with 64 bit of rxtxserial.dll.But it did  not work.

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the error when you used 64 bit ? Coz in current case its clearly states that it cant load 32 bit

Comment: You should post list of  things you tried and attach the corresponding log to each. At the moment there's no other answer than "use the 64bit libs of rxtx".

Comment: Are you positive you're running 32bit? Normally 32bit Java on 64bit Windows goes under `\Program Files (x86)` and 64bit Java goes under `\Program Files` (like other Windows apps). If you type only `java` make sure the directory you want is the first one (or only one) in your PATH; alternatively use the full name in your run command and PATH doesn't matter. (Netbeans is configured which JRE(s) to use and doesn't depend on PATH; you apparently have Netbeans right.)